# LibTiff.Net color image conversion

Tags: c#, bitmap, libtiff, libtiff.net

I am using Bit Miracle LibTiff.Net.

I cannot find any sample code to take a 32bpp ARGB colour image and write the bitmap to a TIFF using this library.

Has anyone else attempted this?

Here is my sample code. It produces a file, but it cannot be viewed by any software that I have.

**EDIT: The code now works, but the colors are wrong!**

```
public static void WriteTiff(Image image, string fileName)
{
    Bitmap target = image as Bitmap;
    BitmapData bmd = target.LockBits(
        target.GetRectangle(),
        ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
        PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    var bits = new byte[bmd.Stride * bmd.Height];
    Marshal.Copy(bmd.Scan0, bits, 0, bits.Length);
    target.UnlockBits(bmd);

    Tiff tiff = Tiff.Open(fileName, "w");
    tiff.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH, target.Width);
    tiff.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH, target.Height);
    tiff.SetField(TiffTag.COMPRESSION, Compression.NONE);
    tiff.SetField(TiffTag.PHOTOMETRIC, Photometric.RGB);
    tiff.SetField(TiffTag.BITSPERSAMPLE, 8);
    tiff.SetField(TiffTag.SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 4);
    tiff.SetField(TiffTag.ROWSPERSTRIP, target.Height);
    tiff.SetField(TiffTag.PLANARCONFIG, PlanarConfig.CONTIG);

    tiff.WriteEncodedStrip(0, bits, bits.Length);
    tiff.Close();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
The latest build of [LibTiff.Net](https://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) contains samples for conversion of a System.Drawing.Bitmap to [32-bit](https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/tree/master/Samples/BitmapTo32BitColorTiff) or [24-bit](https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/tree/master/Samples/BitmapTo24BitColorTiff) color LZW compressed TIFF images.

There is also samples for conversion of a TIFF image to [32-bit](https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/tree/master/Samples/TiffTo32BitBitmap) or [24-bit](https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/tree/master/Samples/TiffTo24BitBitmap) System.Drawing.Bitmaps.
**/EDIT**

You may also want to review "Graphics programming with LibTiff.Net" ([part 1](https://bitmiracle.github.io/libtiff.net/help/articles/KB/black-and-white.html), [part 2](https://bitmiracle.github.io/libtiff.net/help/articles/KB/grayscale-color.html)) article
in documentation. It should give you basic information about creating
color TIFF files.

Disclaimer: I am one of the maintainers of the library.